# AddEventListener function won't execute

Tags: javascript, html

The iFrameOn function runs on page load, and up until it is supposed to execute the iBold function is works fine. I've gone through and debugged as much as possible, and everything *seems* fine. When I output every variable to the console, the values are correct. It's just that one line (`iBold(targetiFrame);`) that won't run. I'm not sure what's going on.

```
function iFrameOn() { 
    var iFrames = document.querySelectorAll('form > iframe'); //Get all iframes in forms
    var bolds = new Array(), italics = new Array(), underlines = new Array(), targetiFrame;
var getRT = document.getElementsByClassName('richText');
    for (var rtIndex = 0; rtIndex < getRT.length;rtIndex++) { //Rich text event listeners
        var rtid = getRT[rtIndex].id;
        if (getRT[rtIndex].className == "richText bold") { //Bold text event listener
            console.log('The id is: '+rtid);
            bolds.push(rtid);
            console.log('The bolds array contains: '+bolds);
        } else if (getRT[rtIndex].className == 'richText underline') { //Underline text event listener
            underlines.push(getRT[rtIndex]);
        } else if (getRT[rtIndex].className == 'richText italic') { //Italic text event listener
            italics.push(getRT[rtIndex]);   
        }   
    }
    bolds.forEach(function(e, i, a) { //e = a[i]
        console.log('e is '+e);
        document.getElementById(e).addEventListener('click', function() {
            console.log(e+' was clicked!');
            targetiFrame = document.getElementById(e).getAttribute('data-pstid');
            iBold(targetiFrame);
        }, false);
    });
}

function iBold(target) { 
    if (target == 0) {
        document.getElementById('richTextField').contentDocument.execCommand('bold', false, null); 
        document.getElementById('richTextField').contentWindow.focus();
    } else {
        document.getElementById(target).contentDocument.execCommand('bold', false, null); 
        document.getElementById(target).contentWindow.focus();
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean "won't run"?

Comment: By "won't run", I mean nothing happens. The iBold function is supposed to allow users to bold text (something akin to the bold functionality of stackoverflow), but after clicking the link that runs the function and typing, text remains normal as if the function wasn't run.

Comment: Fixed it. I apparently had another iBold function in another js file...

Comment: Would you answer your own question then?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I apparently had another iBold function in another js file